# VBA in Excel - Passing External Workbook to worksheetfunction.formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working through an Excel VBA macro that iterates through a sheet and puts dynamic formulas in certain cells. The formula stays the same, but it needs to reference an external workbook that will change often.

At the beginning of my sub, I ask for user input where the user selects the file. I open that file and then start using it. This works perfectly fine, but I cannot figure out how to properly reference that workbook in a formula.

My code, trimmed down to just the lines in question:

```
MsgBox ("Select the PO items workbook sheet with key in column A.")
POI_inputfile = Application.GetOpenFilename
Set po_items = Workbooks.Open(POI_inputfile, False)
Do Until i = bottom_cell
    'lookup of MC against PO line item
     wb_out.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c2").Offset(i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(H" & i + 2 & "&I" & i + 2 & ",'[" & poi_importfile & "]Export'!$A:$E,5,FALSE)"
         i = i + 1
Loop
```

I think the issue is how I'm handling this formula and passing in the workbook, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Help appreciated!

Comment: `POI_inputfile` as variable versus `poi_importfile` in your formula. Using [OptionExplicit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=201706121825028747477) at beginning of every module and compiling code will help with these issues.

Comment: Replace `poi_importfile` with `po_items.Name`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mark this as closed - both comments on my original question were correct but [A.S.H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926357/a-s-h) was correct in that I should be using the .Name property.